# Rails Stack Level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get more information from an error like this?

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
script/rails:6: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Comment: try with tail -f log/development.log. do you remember the last changes  you did to the app?

Comment: It's only when run in production. The logs aren't of much help since it seems to crash too early. I do have version control and have pinpointed the commit where the error was introduced, so I'll have to look through it to figure out what was introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was only occurring in production.

When changing settings inside `config/environments/production.rb`, I found that setting `config.cache_classes = false` let me boot the app in production. Upon reviewing the commit I found the offending class.

I had created a model called `Object` which seemed to have interfered with the way caching works, likely overwriting a core ruby `Object` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's a loop. To have more details of this, you et `"config.log_level = :debug"` in the config/environments/production.rb  and restart your server

Comment: Still unable to learn from changing the log level. It crashes too early.